# Is there a way for a page controller method to override a directive method?

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

Can a page controller override a directive's behavior?

So,

```
scope.doSomething = function() {
   // whatever in the directive
};

$scope.doSomething = function() {
   // do a different whatever than the directive
};
```

Basically, the directive will have the same behavior for every case but one (the override), where the behavior is "Don't do anything", just display.

Comment: The directive can try to get the function from `$parent` scope (e.g. `($parent.someFunc || defaultFunc).apply(this, args)`). HOWEVER: you should probably try to avoid that. It sounds like you're coupling your view to your controller too tightly. An alternative might be to have two directives, one that does the display logic, and one that runs the function (and does whatever else). In most cases you can put both of them on your DOM element in the HTML, but maybe when you only want to display the element, just use the "display" directive.

Comment: @DRobinson unless there's an isoloate scope, can't you kind of assume the parent scope and directive are going to be tightly coupled in some regard? So, why would that be a bad idea? I'm pretty crappy at Angular, so I could be completely off my rocker here. =)

Comment: Well basically, directives should usually act as interfaces. If you pass them everything that they need, they should just work, without having to reach up any levels. To explain, and I failed to suggest an attribute at first, but that's probably what you're after; something like `<some-directive some-useful-fn="sayHello"></some-directive>` would be preferred to `scope.$parent.sayHello()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive should use its attributes to define an interface for any additional parameters that it may need.

```
angular.module('theApp', []).directive('someDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            formattingFn: '=',
        },
        template: "<div> {{viewableData}} </div>",
        link: function(scope){
            // Don't do this in the real world - make sure it quacks first:
            scope.viewableData = (scope.formattingFn || defaultFormat)("Hello World");
        }
    };
    function defaultFormat(data){ 
        return data; 
    }
});
```

Which would then be used In one of two ways, the former will use your function, the latter will not:

```
<div some-directive formatting-fn="doSomething"></div>
<div some-directive></div>
```

The idea is that you build an interface through the directive's `scope`